# Respect django tables order

Tags: python, django

is there any way to make django respect the data base order once I make migrations?, I constantly make some changes and when I see the data base tables the order changes and it is a bit disgusting.

Comment: What you mean by _database order_?

Answer (score 1):

Set order by id for example
in Models.py

```
class Meta:
   ordering = ['id']
```

or Set you own ordering in  `ordering =`